# How much methane clathrates are buried in continental deposits?

Tags: economic-geology, gas, methane, clathrates

[Methane clathrates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methane_clathrate) are

> solid clathrate compound (more specifically, a clathrate hydrate) in which a large amount of methane is trapped within a crystal structure of water, forming a solid similar to ice.

They mostly are on the bottom of the world's oceans; however, the overly brief [wikipedia section for continental](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methane_clathrate#Continental) deposits suggests that it also occurs in Siberia, northern Canada and Alaska.

**How much methane clathrates are believed to be buried in these continental deposits?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Role of methane clathrates in past and future climates](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00144504),

> Methane occurrences and the organic carbon content of sediments are
>   the bases used to estimate the amount of carbon currently stored as
>   clathrates. The estimate of about 11,000 Gt of carbon for ocean
>   sediments, and about 400 Gt for sediments under permafrost
>   regions...

So 400 billion tons.